# HP Deskjet 6127 for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printer, hp-deskjet

I'm having trouble getting a DeskJet 6127 installed on Windows 7 Professional 32 bit.

HP's site recommends using the DeskJet 990c driver, but yet when I go to download it, it is not available for Windows 7 either.

I then followed their steps going through Windows Update to search for the driver, but it didn't find anything. So right now Windows recognizes it as an "unknown device". Has anyone successfully got the DeskJet 6127 to work with Windows 7?

If so, what did you do or point me in the right direction? I'm about to pull my hair out (what's left of it anyways) trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when the drivers are not posted on the HP site for a specific printer its because they're included in the windows pre-loaded print drivers. This one didn't however, have a listing on the windows pre-supported listed printers. I looked the driver up on the HP site follow link bellow. You'll need to select the correct operating system if it's windows 7 most likely your on 32 bit.

[Here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=86858&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&cc=us)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had already been through that link you sent me and it didn't work. Actually running that download on that page pointed me to the 990c driver. Good ol' HP for ya...

Comment: So the 990c driver failed to install using Windows Update or just didn't work after install?